# Sudden issue with Python installation via Homebrew

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew

I have Python 3.12 and virtualenv 20.25.0, both installed via Homebrew.  The last time I used my computer, virtualenv was functioning properly.  The very next time I try to use `virtualenv`, I am greeted with this error:

```
> $ virtualenv --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv.app_data import make_app_data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/virtualenv/app_data/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .read_only import ReadOnlyAppData
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/virtualenv/app_data/read_only.py", line 5, in <module>
    from virtualenv.util.lock import NoOpFileLock
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/virtualenv/util/lock.py", line 12, in <module>
    from filelock import FileLock, Timeout
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filelock'
```

The internet happens to not be very helpful and I have done nothing myself in the time between using virtualenv successfully and now.  What could've happened here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install virtualenv` [installs `filelock`](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/5ad4de304a8e0344d0c3084c31f129119e50a377/pyproject.toml#L46) as a dependency. If Homebrew didn't install `filelock` it's a bug in its formulas.

Try to fix by installing `filelock` directly:

```
sudo python3.12 -m pip install --break-system-packages filelock
```

If that doesn't help try to upgrade the entire stack of dependencies for `virtualenv`:

```
sudo python3.12 -m pip install --break-system-packages --upgrade virtualenv
```

PS. I often recommend to avoid `sudo` but this time it's required to fix/upgrade what is installed under `/usr/local`

Comment: These commands display a message like: "error: externally-managed-environment To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to install. ... note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages."  Is it safe to pass that flag in this case?  Should I maybe try downgrading `virtualenv` if you think it's a problem with the formula?

Comment: And I'm not really sure how to read Homebrew formulae, but this appears to specify filelock as a dependency: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/bad6b2c872681dcb14f6339e662a009ce4d04d91/Formula/v/virtualenv.rb

Comment: Try to uninstall and re-install `virtualenv` using Homebrew from scratch. If that doesn't help try `sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.12 -m pip install --break-system-packages --upgrade virtualenv`

Comment: Uninstalling/reinstalling `virtualenv` via Homebrew didn't work, but the pip install with `--break-system-packages` did fix it.  Thank you.  Still confused by this happening out of nowhere though.

Comment: I know very little about Homebrew, cannot help with it. I added `--break-system-packages` to the answer.